# Manipulating IP addresses - split string on '.' character

Tags: java, regex

```
String address = "192.168.1.1";
```

I want to split the address and the delimiter is the point.
So I used this code:

```
String [] split = address.split(".");
```

But it didn't work, when I used this code it works:

```
String [] split = address.split("\\.");
```

so why splitting the dot in IPv4 address is done like this : `("\\.")` ?

Comment: `.` has a special meaning in the regexp (any char). To match `.` you have to escape it with ``\``, but java uses ``\`` as escape character, so you have to escape ``\`` again with a ``\``. This leads to ``\\.``. This literal printed gives us ``\.`` and is what regexp sees.

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the "." as `split` takes a regex. But you also need to escape the escape as "\." won't work in a java `String`:

```
String [] split = address.split("\\.");
```

This is because the backslash in a java `String` denotes the beginning of a [character literal](http://www.roseindia.net/java/language/java-literals.shtml).

Comment: Thank you now I got the idea

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB you've asked 7 questions and accepted no answers.  Sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

You should split like this, small tip use Pattern.compile as well

```
String address = "192.168.1.1";
String[] split = address.split("\\.");// you can replace it with private static final Pattern.
```